# Changing the Color of a Row in a SharePoint List (using JSON) based on a columns value

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

So I have a SharePoint list with a column called modified. I used the following code to change the rows colors based on when it was last modified which works fine:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if([$Modified] < @now && [$Modified] >= @now - 86400000, 'sp-field-severity--blocked', if([$Modified] < @now && [$Modified] >= @now - 259200000, 'sp-field-severity--warning' , ''))"
}
```

However, now I want it to be a dark grayish color instead of red. I have tried many different things, but cannot get it too work for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if([$Modified] < @now && [$Modified] >= @now - 86400000, 'ms-bgColor-gray120', if([$Modified] < @now && [$Modified] >= @now - 259200000, 'sp-field-severity--warning' , ''))"
}
```

This will apply `ms-bgColor-gray120` class for first condition (`[$Modified] < @now && [$Modified] >= @now - 86400000`).

Similarly, you can apply any of the predefined classes given in below links as per your requirements:

1. [Predefined classes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#predefined-classes)
2. [Reusable SharePoint Online Classes for Modern UI](https://zerg00s.github.io/sp-modern-classes/)